# How to move selcted files from one doc library to another doc library?

Tags: 2013, document-library

I followed below link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/08/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments

and i got upto fetching docs and show in popup,i am trying to move these docs to destination document library,but i didn't get any solution.
Can anyone please send process on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code to move files from one Document library to another document library programmatically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
namespace MoveTo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://serverName:1111/SitePages/Home.aspx"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPFileCollection collFile = web.GetFolder("Shared Documents").Files;
                    int count = collFile.Count;
                    while (count != 0)
                    {
                        collFile[count - 1].MoveTo("Destination Library/" + collFile[count - 1].Name, true);
                        count--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can user `SPQuery`  to filter files from document library on above mentioned code...

Another method is to create ribbon button & get selected files on that button click event & move them to another document library.

Happy Coding.... :)

Comment: Is my answer correct for your question?. if it is a proper solution for you than Please mark as correct so it will helpful to others as well... Thanks...

Comment: but i want selectd files only not move to all files in doc lib.

Answer (score 1):

Using GUI, you can open Explorer View and make simple drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: i know that one but i want through programmatically.

Comment: Something like that? http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/04/programmatically-copy-and-move-documents-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thank u for ur response,in this artical the destination file mentioned as static,but i want dynamically.

Comment: I think you can take some ideas from "Select destination" in this article: http://spjsblog.com/category/document-library/